# How to define Vue event modifiers with a render function?

Tags: vue.js, events

I'm trying to create a Vue app with a `render()` function and [`withModifiers`](https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#withmodifiers). But somehow a `keyup.enter` event does not work as expected: It fires for *every* key, not only the enter or return key.

Here is a minimum example:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
    <script>
      const app = Vue.createApp({
        render() {
          return Vue.h("input", { onKeydown: Vue.withModifiers((e) => console.log(e), ["enter"]) });
        },
      }).mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Seems to be for event modifiers, while enter is key modifier

Comment: @EstusFlask Oh, I wasn't aware that there's a difference. Do you think there's a way to achieve the same? Or do I need to filter the keys in the event handler?

Comment: Nothing in the docs suggests that. You can check the sources, I see there's undocumented withKeys that serves the purpose

Comment: [Here](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#v-on) it says: "For other event and key modifiers, the withModifiers helper can be used". Anyway, I'll look into `withKeys`.

Comment: Oh yes! `withKeys` is indeed working!